# Are there certain badge acquiring strategies to follow?

Tags: achievements, ingress

When the levels higher than L8 were introduced into the game I've jumped straight to L10 and I'm stuck there since then. My AP is more than 8.4 million which is enough for L12 but I'm still struggling to get to L11.

I've already achieved two black badges with recharging and guardian badges but as I'm an urban player I don't have the same portal density in my area as a metropolitan player does and so I can't get to the next badge levels as fast as they do.

Was it a mistake for me to achieve those black badges so early, and if so are there some other guidelines to follow to raise the badge levels more equally?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, that wasn't a mistake. Badges levels are cumulative, so a black badge counts also as a bronze, silver and gold badge in terms of requirements. Also, badges gained early still count for the requirements of later levels.

This is better explained by this image:

[image: Ingress progression 9-16]

As you can see those two black badges will still count all the way through level 16, so you'd only need 2 more platinum badges and three gold badges to meet the requirements to get to level cap.

This lets you use any strategy you prefer. You can even concentrate on a badge at a time, knowing that your progress is "saved" for later levels.

Answer (score 2):

From my observations I can say that usually people at levels 1-8 struggle to get the AP (obviously), once they get to lvl 8 it's the badge hunting till level 12 or so, and then it's again the AP that's missing for level 12-16

Given this, your strategy will depend on you long-term goals. If you don't want to get higher than 12 then ideally you should focus on badges from the first day on, the AP will follow automatically. If you want to get to level 16, then focus on getting as much AP as possible from the first day on, by the time you have the AP required for higher levels you will also have the necessary badges automatically.